# Peer-to-peer replication fails due to missing sp_MS* stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

We've had a two node peer-to-peer (P2P) replication setup running for almost a year but for some reason it was recently marked as inactive forcing us to re-build it. Unfortunately no matter how I try to re-build it I keep getting the same error.

Basically once P2P is configured it would instantly fail because it couldn’t find some auto-created “sp_MS[upd|ins|del]*******” stored procedures. While doing some investigation (and selecting directly from sys.procedures) I found that these stored procedures are only created when the DB becomes a subscriber as a P2P node, similar to transactional replication. As every DB in P2P is a publisher and a subscriber the fact that these were missing is strange especially considering it clearly succeeds in doing this on one of the DBs but not the other. It would appear that one of the DBs does not get set up as a subscriber but I receive no error or indication of this (in fact Management Studio does show two subscriptions). I tried pretty much everything I could think of, changing which DB is configured first, completely disabling distribution and re-creating it, etc. but still no luck.

Has anyone else run into this or could does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should look at trying next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any time i've had to do it, i just use SSMS.    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152536%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.  However if you are starting from scratch, I'd make sure all traces of replication are removed via sp_removedbreplication.

Comment: That's what I've been tried and have also used sp_removedbreplication. It seems very similar to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2931001 but that should be fixed in the version I'm using.

Comment: what version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the database that the P2P backup was taken from was modified before it was restored on the new node. This happened even when the option specifying that a change has happened was used and is likely a bug. The "solution" is to ensure that the original DB has not been modified **at all** before replication gets back up and running.